# Spelling Bug on new profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

when I hover over the `helpful flags button on the new profile page setup, the tooltip that pops up has a spelling error.

It says **`Helpul flags`**, when it should really say `Helpful flags`.

[image]

Comment: Why is that tooltip even there? That's about as useless as a tooltip can get. Should just be removed.

Comment: @BenLee If you click on it now it says`Total number of raised flags marked useful`

Comment: ah, that makes a lot more sense